# Setting request timeout in nsmutablerequest ios

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, settimeout, nsurlrequest

I need to set up a 30 second time out into my application when it tries to connect a web service. I have tried cachePolicy:timeoutInterval, but that does not have any effect. My code is below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myservice.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;

webData =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
webData = (NSMutableData *) [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: I cannot see that you set a timeout interval in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.

Basically, `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` doesn't obey the `timeoutInterval` that is passed in for small intervals, while, asynchronous requests do.

If you think about how things work, this becomes obvious: synchronous requests are blocking, and, there is no easy way for a watchdog to check for timeouts -- the thread is being blocked!. Asynchronous requests don't block the thread, so, it can check for timeouts every runloop run.

Comment: I am not sure if this is true, in particular because the documentation states that "A synchronous load is built on top of the asynchronous loading code made available by the class.".

Comment: is there a way through which i can set the delegate of NSUrlConnection without changing my code completely?

Comment: @HassanZaheer `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` is the least impactful way to get async loading. As a quick hack, you could move everything below your `sendSynchronousRequest` call into the async completion block.